# FTP - Uploading a file in a diffrent name

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, ftp, webclient

I have a form which has radiobuttons, each of them is giving a file name in a string, and what I want to do is to have that string as a name for any file that a user uploads.

It'll be great if you could explain to me how to rename, because I already got it the code to upload **or** just help me modify this function, I would probably have to add to the parameters "string type" tho:

```
public void uploadFTP(string filename, string type, string password, ProgressBar progressbar)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", password);

    try
    {
        client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(@"ftp://ftpaddress.com" + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name), "STOR", filename);
    }
    catch(System.InvalidCastException)
    {
        // Handled it
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentException)
    {
        // Handled it
    }
    client.UploadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    };
    client.UploadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Upload complete", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    };
}
```

If it's important: The files are RTF (RichTextBox).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Could you please clarify? My understanding is that you want to rename a file that you have uploaded. Why not rename the local file first and then upload it? That would be a lot easier, and faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to rename file with c# ftp methods when current user directory is different from root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035610/unable-to-rename-file-with-c-ftp-methods-when-current-user-directory-is-differen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just upload to different URL then. Replace `new FileInfo(filename).Name` in your code with the name you actually want. Also, I think not using string manipulation is better. And the STOR command is the default.

```
client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(new Uri("ftp://ftpaddress.com"), newName)), filename);
```