# How can I get file from FTP (using C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Now I know how to copy files from one directory to another, this is really simple.

But now I need to do the same with files from FTP server. Can you give me some example how to get file from FTP while changing its name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [How to: Download Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx) or [downloading all files in directory ftp and c#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ncl/thread/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3)

```
 // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            response.Close();
```

**Edit**
If you want to rename file on FTP Server take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035610/unable-to-rename-file-with-c-sharp-ftp-methods-when-current-user-directory-is-di)

Comment: I would enclose your reader in a using block for proper disposal. Otherwise, add reader.Dispose() at the end.

Comment: I know this is a copy / paste of the MS content, but it's still not cleanly written.

Comment: I understand that I need to save file in my local dict and only then  - rename it? but can I do it directly?

Comment: You want to rename file that exists on FTP?

Comment: I don't need to rename file on ftp, but I need to save file that I get from ftp with new name

Comment: Just rename the file once you have saved it. You can use File.Copy to rename file. First Copy/paste it with new name and and then delete the original file

Answer (score 8):

### Easiest way

The most trivial way to download a binary file from an FTP server using .NET framework is using [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile).

It takes an URL to the source remote file and a path to the target local file. So you can use a different name for the local file, if you need that.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadFile(
    "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip", @"C:\local\path\file.zip");
```

---

### Advanced options

If you need greater control, that `WebClient` does not offer (like [TLS/SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555), ASCII mode, active mode, etc), use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest). Easy way is to just copy an FTP response stream to `FileStream` using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

---

### Progress monitoring

If you need to monitor a download progress, you have to copy the contents by chunks yourself:

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int read;
    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
    }
}
```

For GUI progress (WinForms `ProgressBar`), see:
[FtpWebRequest FTP download with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45269263/850848)

---

### Downloading folder

If you want to download all files from a remote folder, see
[C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848).